# No available bundle exports package 'org.restlet.resource'

Tags: java, manifest, restlet

I tried to do this tutorial : http://ntabakov.wordpress.com/2011/12/
    I have a problem in step 4 of the tutorial. 
    I have downloaded and added in the build path org.restlet.jar

```
In the manifest file  I have this error :

> No available bundle exports package 'org.restlet.resource'
in this line :

in this line :
Import-Package: example.restlet.hello.service, org.restlet.resource


my manifest file is : 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloBundleRestService
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloBundleRestService
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: ntabakov.wordpress.com
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: example.restlet.hello.service,
 org.restlet.resource
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/HelloServiceResource.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a jar of Restlet which is not a bundle, just a simple jar.
There is a dedicated edition called "OSGi" for that: http://restlet.com/download/current#release=stable&edition=osgi&distribution=zip